# Can ICA be applied to solve BSS problem in frequency domain?

Tags: signal-analysis, ica

I'm recently doing research on [EMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference), and I want to seperate the mixing signals. However, the data given is in frequency domain. As I have used [ICA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis) to solve blind source separation problem in time domain, can this be used to solve [BSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signal_separation) in frequency domain? And how? I can not imagine how this would work. I would appreciate if you could provide me some extra materials on this subjects!

Comment: Perhaps you could use less acronyms. Not everyone knows what EMI, ICA and BSS stand for.

Comment: EMI means electromagnet interference, and ICA means independent component analysis, BSS stands for blind source separation.